# Internal Server Error for a HTTP POST request

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, httprequest

I am having a script activity that Posts an HTTP request. The issue is that sometimes, the request returns internal error(500). However, since this is an error and not an exception, my catch block does not handles this and my script activity just fails. The response from API(when tried in POSTMAN) is also just like below:

```
{
"detail": "An internal error occurred"
}
```

I want to have a graceful mechanism to handle this. I am not able to check the status code, because the script just fails. How can handle this error in my code?

The code that calls the API is as below:

```
function getRecommendations(arrayofUsersNeedRecommendation, recommenderSettingsObj) {
  
        var rows = 0;

      var status = [0];
         var result = [];
         var headerNames =  ['x-client-id'];
         var headerValues = [recommenderSettingsObj.API_KEY];
         var today = new Date();
         var contentType = "text/plain";

 try{

  result = HTTP.Post(recommenderSettingsObj.REQUEST_URL, contentType, arrayofUsersNeedRecommendation, headerNames, headerValues);
    Write("StatusCode"+result.StatusCode); //This return status code of 200 in case of success. In case of 500, the scrit errors.
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    Write(Stringify(e));
    rows = handleError(Stringify(e));
  }
```

This is the postman response:

[image]

Comment: It would actually help if you would let us see what code you have there, otherwise, it would be a blind guess.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

This may not directly answer your question. [As you have not/does not want to share code. Please refer the below code snipped which might help you to customize your code and debug the response.

Also I would suggest to update the status code. I see you cannot see from script; but you can check the status code in POSTMAN.

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
var fname = Platform.Request.GetFormField('fname');
var mob = Platform.Request.GetFormField('mob');
var email = Platform.Request.GetFormField('email');

var payload =   {   client_id: "xxxx",
                    client_secret: "xxx",
                    grant_type: "xxxx",
                    account_id: "xxxx"
                };
var url = 'https://xxxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
var contentType = 'application/json';
try {   var resp = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));


        if(resp.StatusCode != 200) 
        {
           //Error from API
        }
        if(resp.StatusCode == 200) 
        {
           //Success from your API request
           // continue processing
        }


    }

    catch (error) 
    {
        Write("Inside ERROR <br/><br/>");
        Write(Stringify(error));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question :)